# Implementing virtual mouse (clicks,move) within a browser inside a Java Application

Tags: java, mouse

I'm wondering if it's possible and if so how, could you potentially load a website, and have a means of clicking something without it having to take control of your actual mouse.

I don't know if anyone here is familiar with Runescape, but I've seen bots from that game where it has its own window, can log into the game and somehow click and move around all the while you're able to retain your own mouse control and do your own thing. I was hoping I could do something like that, but with a website rather than a game. Anyone have any ideas? I've tried searching around but haven't gotten far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need two things:

1. Robot class for allow Java to take control over your mouse and keyboard
   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html
2. Ability to take global events outside your Java application (normally it's impossible to capture event outside your app)
   https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/